# magento 2.2.8 Configurable product: Changing color showing second gallery image as selected

Tags: configurable-product, gallery, magento2.2.8

I am using `Magento 2.2.8` and facing a weird issue on Product Detail Page.

On the Product Details Page, my gallery shows the wrong image as selected, instead of the first one.

**Steps:**

> 1. Land on Product Details Page.
> 2. Click on second image in the Product gallery.
> 3. Change the Product color
> 4. Image gallery refresh itself and instead of first image which is the
>      main image, it show the second image as selected.

I am using Porto theme, verified it on Luma as well and getting the same issue on it.

I am trying to find and fix the cause, if someone directs me on

the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: By dault the first image of a child of a configurable product is shown. so if your having issues with your images id recommend checking the simple products

Comment: yes it is working fine for the first iamge, but if you select the second image and then change the color it keep displaying the second image as selected,

Comment: Is that second image defined within the simple product on the selected value? if so then it will do if not then possibly a issue with the gallery and the config var in magneto the best way to check this would be to view the page source and paste the config info

Comment: sorry for the delay, no the second image is not defined on selected value.

Comment: @Tech2PakTech2Pak did you solve this issue?
i am also getting this same issue